# How to query an Array in SqlAlchemy / Postgres

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table that looks like this...

```
class Company(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'company'
    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    slug = db.Column(db.String)
    tags = db.Column(ARRAY(db.Integer), index=True)

    investments = relationship("Investment", back_populates="company")
```

I want to write a query that returns all rows that have a certain integer (say 6) in the array (tag column), I tried the following which I took from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543977/filter-with-array-column-with-postgres-and-sqlalchemy)

```
(1) investors = db.session.query(Investor).filter(Company.tags.any(6)).all()
(2) investors = db.session.query(Investor).filter(Company.tags.contains([6]))
```

(1) Gives me the following error...

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) missing FROM-clause entry for table "company"
LINE 3: WHERE 6 = ANY (company.tags)
```

(2) Gives me unexpected behavior. It either returns nothing or all the information. The filter isn't working. 
                       ^