# Sqlalchemy How to query citext array

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Using `sqlalchemy` expression language how can I query a `postgresSQL` `CITEXT` array?

SQL:

```
SELECT id FROM message_list WHERE recipients @> ARRAY['user@example.com']::citext[];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23545530/2681632

Comment: Is `recipients` itself a `citext[]` column?

Comment: @Ilja Everilä Actually `message_list` is view. `Message_recipients` is another relation and address is `citext[]` column. Definition: `array_agg(message_recipient.address ORDER BY message_recipient.header_id) AS recipients,...` I was able to query using `messagelist.c.recipients.any('user@example.com')`. I wish I could make it work like: `messagelist.c.recipients.any('%user@example.com%')`

Comment: `messagelist.c.recipients.contains(['user@...'])` would produce the `@>` expression, given that the view is correctly reflected/defined. If you want `LIKE ANY`, try the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42573552/2681632

Comment: `... messagelist.c.recipients.like(any_(to))...` produces `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) operator does not exist: citext[] ~~ unknown
LINE 3: ...st.subject ILIKE 'HI' AND message_list.recipients LIKE ANY (...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: As for `...messagelist.c.recipients.contains['user@...']` - TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Well, the latter is obviosly wrong: you're using subscript access on a method instead of calling it with a list argument. The former is not so clear and kindof underlines the fact that this question would benefit from a [mcve].